# Using htaccess to redirect all subdomains except one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mobile, subdomain

current htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

I also have a subdomain :
m.mywebsite.co.uk
I don't want this "m." domain redirected, but all other subdomains that exist or not directed to www.mywebsite.co.uk including "mywebsite.co.uk"

Can you help?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.mywebsite\.co\.uk$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mywebsite\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Using your code if a user inputs: "mm.mywebsite.co.uk" it redirects to : "mm.www.mywebsite.co.uk" when it should redirect to: "www.mywebsite.co.uk"
Also "wwww.mywebsite.co.uk" doesnt get redirected to www

Comment: Clear your browser's cache and retest the rule in an empty htaccess.

Comment: That doesn't work. Tried clearing htaccess and refreshing /clearing/ cache etc. but "xxxx.mywebsite.co.uk" doesnt redirect to "www.mywebsite.co.uk"